Magento admin ui grid not loading
I am trying to create an admin grid module which loads custom data. I have created the small module to test the feature. However, the grid is not loading. Below is the code.
Controller:
app/code/Itm/Reports/Controller/Adminhtml/Platform/DriveScores.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Itm\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Platform;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;


class DriveScores extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        private readonly PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(): Page
    {
        $resultPage = $this->initAction();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Drive Scores'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

    private function initAction(): Page
    {
        $resultPage = $this->pageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Itm_Reports::drive_scores');
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Reports'), __('Reports'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Drive Scores'), __('Drive Scores'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}

app/code/Itm/Reports/etc/di.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="reports_platform_drivescores_data_source" xsi:type="string">Itm\Reports\Ui\Component\DataProvider\DriveScores</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>

Custom DataProvider
app/code/Itm/Reports/Ui/Component/DataProvider/DriveScores.php
    <?php
    
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Itm\Reports\Ui\Component\DataProvider;
    
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider;
    
    class DriveScores extends DataProvider
    {
        // Implement the required methods
        public function getData()
        {
            return [
                'totalRecords' => 3,
                'items' => [
                    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'score' => 100],
                    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jane Doe', 'score' => 200],
                    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'John Smith', 'score' => 300],
                ],
            ];
        }
    }

Layout:
app/code/Itm/Reports/view/adminhtml/layout/itm_reports_platform_drivescores.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <uiComponent name="reports_platform_drivescores"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>

app/code/Itm/Reports/view/adminhtml/ui_component/reports_platform_drivescores.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">reports_platform_drivescores.reports_platform_drivescores_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">reports_platform_drivescores.reports_platform_drivescores_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">reports_platform_drivescores_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="reports_platform_drivescores_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Itm\Reports\Ui\Component\DataProvider\DriveScores</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">reports_platform_drivescores_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render" />
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="reports_platform_drivescores_columns">
            <selectionsColumn name="ids">
                <settings>
                    <indexField>id</indexField>
                </settings>
            </selectionsColumn>
            <column name="id">
                <settings>
                    <filter>textRange</filter>
                    <label translate="true">ID</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
            <column name="name">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Store ID</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
            <column name="score">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Drive Score</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
    </columns>
</listing>

Can someone point the mistake. I can see the grid layout is not rendered for sure.

To get the exact idea of what is causing issues in loading your grid.

Please enable developer mode in your local environment.

Open the network tab and search for "mui/index/render", It will show the exact error that is occurring while loading the grid records.



